# Find the OpsWorks deploy user in a recipe

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, devops, aws-opsworks

I'm trying to figure out how to extract or find the name of the user who's performing the deployment of an app on a given OpsWorks stack. For example, in the "Deployments and Commands" section of a stack, the table there displays a history of various deployments with who the deploy user was... etc. I'd like to be able to capture that same user from within my recipe.

It doesn't look like it's something I can grab out of `search(:aws_opsworks_app)` databag (unless I'm mistaken). Or is there somewhere else I can get this information easily?

Comment: Do you mean the system user running Chef or like which AWS account initiated the API operation?

Comment: I meant the latter: The AWS user account that initiated the deployment operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there's a pretty simple way to get it through `search(:aws_opsworks_command)` databag.

`:aws_opsworks_command` provides an `iam_user_arn` attribute which can be massaged to appear as the deployment user's IAM name. An example `iam_user_arn` string look like `arn:aws:iam:555555:user/username`

Example:

```
owc = search(:aws_opsworks_command).first
owc[:iam_user_arn].split(':').last
# => gets us "user/username"
```

Documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/data-bag-json-command.html